# Changing python version environment inside python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, python-2.x

I have two python scripts, first one (script1) works with python2 and second one 
(script2) works with python3.

They are two codes that I have not written by myself, and I have tried running the first one with python3 or runnig the second one with python2 it wont work.

What I need is to call the script1 many times from script2 (so in script2, I need to call script1 with passing some arguments such as x, y)

So definitely because script1 should run in python2 and script2 should run in python3, I need to change the running environment.

I tried this:

```
    os.system("source activate py3") #py3 is a virtualenv in which python3 is installed
    #running codes on python3
    os.system("source deactivate py3")
    script1.main(x, y)
```

however, it seems it doesnt work. if I run `python3 script2.py` everything will run based on python3 and if I run `python script2.py` everything will run based on python2.

So it means writing os.system("command to change python version environment") wont work.

Is there any other solution for this?

I appreciate your consideration.
Thanks in advnace

Comment: Run the script with the full path to the interpreter in the virtual environment: `/your/env/bin/python yourscript.py ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.system("source activate py3") #py3 is a virtualenv in which python3 is installed
```

You have run a shell command: `source activate py3`. That shell command can only have effects inside the call `os.system`. It doesn't do much and once it's over, your script carry on inside the interpreter, which is already either your `python2`

So:

```
#running codes on python3
os.system("source deactivate py3")
```

the code is **NOT** running on `python3`, because whatever you did with `os.system` had only effects within that call.

One option

```
os.system('mypy3.sh')
```

Your `mypy3.sh` will look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
source bin/activate
python script_with_python3_code
```